# PayPal Magento2 Re curing Subscription

Tags: magento2

hello i have Some course which is subscription product like a month year week and i i want to create subscription using paypal express checkout in magento2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

out of the box, Magento 2 does not have any subscription(Recurring) product and AFAIK it is a big concept so might be you need to buy some 3rd party extensions from Marketplace or you need to implement by own

Comment: yes i know its not in magento2 currently but if i create my own extension how i can do this